# Macro for both excel and openoffice calc

Tags: python, vba, openoffice-calc, code-conversion

I am in need of creating a macro that will launch on both excel and openoffice calc. My first problem is format of a file that I should create (xls vs ods) to be able to open it in both applications.

Another problem is creating a macro, what language I should use to allow launching it using both Excel and OO Calc?

I'm pretty sure VBA macro won't launch on OpenOffice since it's quite complicated case, but I'm afraid StarBasic will not run on Excel.

I am aware of python that should launch on both applications, but my knowledge of python is insufficient (I could use VBA/SB -> python converted if there is any).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenOffice default Macro language (OOoBasic / StarBasic) is similar to VB however is not the same and if you try to reuse macros written in VB in OpenOffice or StarBasic in Office it won't work. 
I worked professionally developing macros and I don't know any method to convert code between VBA and SB. I recommend you to use python, however I believe it will be possible only if you don't use some advanced programing options. If you plan to use OpenOffice objects (services) ([OOo services here](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/module-ix.html)) those will not work in Microsoft office because the object control is different.